# Automatically shutting down the Pi after it's been idle for a certain period of time

Tags: cron

I'm using my Raspberry Pi as a music server : I've installed MPD running under Archlinux ARM.

I'd like to set a cronjob that would check wether MPD has been active for a given period of time and if it's beeni inactive, safely shutdown the system by issuing a shutdown -h now command.

How can I check wether a daemon has been active or not in the last XXX minutes.

Answer (score 2):

you may check if the program is running with `pgrep -c mpd`, that outputs `0` if no such program is found, otherwise `1` (or `2` or more).

<s>please define "active" ?</s>

ok, you want to know the status of the current song in mpd. the easiest way could be using [python-mpd](https://github.com/magcius/python-mpd/blob/d75c186aed6aa613e5f8c6e379d6f9d39e844c5b/mpd.py) and a little bit of python scripting:

```
>>> status = client.status()
>>> status['state']
'play'        # or 'pause' or 'stop'
```

you may setup your python script to run at the regular intervals using `cron` and check the current `mpd` status. if it's playing, save the current time to some file, otherwise calculate the difference between the current time and the last saved playing time, if the difference exceeds your threshold, issue `shutdown` command.

Comment: By active, I mean that mpd outputs audio content. I'm looking for a way to check wether mpd has been outputting content for the last XXX minutes, for example.

Comment: @Thomas see updated answer